# Can the Marauder's Map detect a person under Harry's Invisibility Cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-items, marauders-map

The [Marauder's Map](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marauder%27s_Map) was able to detect & display everyone in Hogwarts. I am just curious if it could detect inside Harry's [Invisibility Cloak](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility_cloak), which was used successfully against even death. As function of both magical objects are opposite, I can re-frame the question as follows: Marauder's Map vs. Invisibility Cloak - which will win?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, Lupin addresses that very issue:

> “The number of times I saw James disappearing under it…” said Lupin, waving an impatient hand again. “The point is, even if you’re wearing an Invisibility Cloak, you still show up on the Marauder’s Map. I watched you cross the grounds and enter Hagrid’s hut. Twenty minutes later, you left Hagrid, and set off back toward the castle. But you were now accompanied by somebody else.”

See the Harry Potter Wiki on the [The Marauder's Map](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Marauder%27s_Map) for more details.

Comment: Wow, I'd kinda forgotten about that. So it turns out that the invisibility cloak will hide you from death itself - but not from a prank item a bunch of schoolkids made?

Comment: If I had to guess (and this is getting into one of those Fuzzy areas of magic JKR refers to from time to time) I'd say that the fact that one of it's authors was the legitimate holder of the cloak resulted in him giving it an implied or implicit access to see it.  Given that there is only one person we see use the Map to see someone under the cloak, AND that person was one of the authors, it's also possible that no one except one of the 4 authors could use it that way.

Comment: But still its not acceptable.. I could digest it if map would have created by Voldemort because he really challenged death many times, but couldn't for a prank item a bunch of schoolkids made.. :D

Comment: @SachinShekhar, actually Voldemort was terrified of death; I'd say he *never* "challenged death". E.g., Dumbledore to Harry in King's Cross: "You had accepted, even embraced, the possibility of death, something Lord Voldemort has never been able to do."

Comment: @JoeWhite Yup.. he was terrified of death, that's why he did all Horcrux based ju-ju. But, it doesn't mean he didn't challenged death. Even Dumbledore was beaten by death with one magic spell, but that wasn't the case of Voldemort. With all Horcrux in existence, death was never able to beat Voldemort... Horcrux made job of death very hard. What's this? isn't it a challenge? As death isn't an object, you shouldn't apply plain literature around it..

Comment: @KeithHWeston Not completely true.  Harry himself wasn't one of the authors but used the map to identify where he and Luna were located while they were both under the cloak in DH.  So Harry - not an author - was able to identify not only himself but somebody else that was under the cloak.

Comment: @Dason -- Good point.  Side effect of inheriting it, perhaps?  Keeps the chain of stuff going.. DUnno.. To be honest, out of universe, I think JKR never really thought of the whole idea.  Ah, well. it's just a theory -- all we know is that it DOES work.. how and why is another question.

Answer (score 1):

We learn in [Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child) that not only can the cloak's user/s be seen on the map, they can even be seen when the person is **in the room with the map itself**!

> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL** (from off — trying to give them every chance): *I am about to enter.*
>
> PROFESSOR McGONAGALL comes into the room, the Marauder’s Map in her
> hands. The boys disappear beneath the Cloak. She looks around,
> exasperated.
>
> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL [continued]** *Well, where have they — I never wanted this thing and now it’s playing tricks on me.*
>
> She thinks. She looks back at the map. She identifies where they
> should be. She looks around the room. Objects move as the boys
> invisibly move past them. She sees where they’re heading, she makes to
> block them. But they skirt around her.
>
> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL [continued]** *Unless. Unless . . . Your father’s Cloak.*
>
> She looks back at the map, she looks at the boys. She smiles to
> herself.
>
> **PROFESSOR McGONAGALL [continued]** *Well, if I didn’t see you, I didn’t see you.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Cursed Child](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29056083-harry-potter-and-the-cursed-child)</sup></sub>

Comment: I would appreciate a warning, _before_ reading that giant quote, that I'm reading a quote from Cursed Child. :)

Comment: @RedCaio - This isn't much of a spoiler. You find out that they're friends in the first five pages and there are no particular plot points being revealed here.

Comment: I didn't say it was a spoiler. I just want to avoid any and all quotes/info from Cursed Child until I can read it. If _I_ were writing a post, I'd just add "we learn in cursed child..." _before_ the quote. :)

Comment: @RedCaio - Fair enough. Mischief managed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a key element of Harry's nighttime adventure with the egg in chapter 25 of *Goblet of Fire* (my emphasis):

> Any moment now, Filch was going to pull aside the tapestry, expecting to see Peeves... and there would be no Peeves... but if he came up the stairs, he would spot the Marauder's Map... **and Invisibility Cloak or not, the map would show "Harry Potter" standing exactly where he was.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the Goblet of Fire, Moody sees Harry on the map, under the cloak.

Comment: Don't have the book handy, but I think you mean Moony, not Moody. To my recollection Moody never had the map.

Comment: @PTBNL No, Moody definitely borrows the map from Harry in GoF. After Harry goes to the prefect's bathroom, he's coming back, gets caught in the trick stair, drops the map and the egg and then gets rescued my Moody, who sees the map, keeps Snape from taking it, and then talks to harry and finds out what it is and asks to borrow it (as an aid for himself and so that harry doesn't see that he's Barty Crouch Jr on the map). There is however absolutely no confirmation I can see that Moody saw harry on the map. Presumably he did, but it's never said, so doesn't count as evidence in answer to this q.